# Backup Outlook data files automatically

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there anyway to backup Outlook data files automatically even if Outlook is running? I thought of a standard task on Task Scheduler and use the `copy` command but it won't copy if Outlook is running. Is there anything within Outlook or Windows? We'll be using Outlook 2010 mainly but I would like to know about both 2010 and newer versions.

Comment: Are you asking how to back up the .pst files whilst in use?

Comment: Yes. I want the process to be automated without intervention as much as possible because asking the users to do anything is a true pain for me.

Comment: And it has to be done during the day? A work around solution which I used to use (many years ago) was a script which would close Outlook, run the back up (starting at 1am or a time when staff were not in). It means back ups are not 100% up to date but was OK for our needs. Do you have the same issue if you use `Robocopy` ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/464226/efficiently-backup-pst-outlook-files

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! :) No I don't think that would work for me. The backup that I want to do will be during their work hours, and If something works I will make it daily, one copy backup.

Comment: The answer to the question you mentioned makes very sense! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by using the Volume Shadow Copy Services (VSS). It basically takes a "snapshot" that you can then take a backup from.

First of all you need to check whether your volume supports this. You can do this by running `vssadmin list volumes` from an admin command prompt.

To create a snapshot, you can run `vssadmin create shadow /for=‹Volume›`.

To access the volume, you first need to find the location of your snapshot, which you can get by running `vssadmin list shadows`. Look for the line that contains something like `Shadow Copy Volume: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy5`. The `\\?\GLOBALTOOR\...`is the path to your snapshot. You can copy whatever file you want from there.

Finally, it may be a good idea to remove the snapshot, since you probably don't want to keep it forever. Use `vssadmin delete shadows /for=‹Volume›`to do this, you need to add one of the parameters `/shadow=‹GUID›`, `/oldest` or `/all`.

If this sounds too complicated, there are backup applications that can also do these steps. An example would be the the open-source application [Duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this helps: [Script to schedule your pst-file back-up](https://www.howto-outlook.com/downloads/backupscript.htm). The script can be used to make a backup archive and have the script start Outlook again once it is done so it almost goes unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could use Windows's inbuilt backup function and select the directory where Outlook files are stored. It may not be as elegant as other solutions, but it should work.

Just setup a schedule to have it backup automatically